# How to store formatted data in Array in Vue, watch and v-model aren't saving formatted data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch, v-model

I have multiple text boxes and when the user types in different text boxes, I want to have an array that stores all this formatted data.

The formatted data is in m:ss (m - minute, s - seconds)

Right now, all the different text boxes show the same value, because there is only one this.formatTime.

How do we change this so that v-model goes through the array, and adds it into an array of formatted values?

The textbox should show the formatted value and store it in allFormatValues[].

I'm really stuck on this, thanks for your time!

```
<div id="app">
   <div
      v-for="(input, index) in valueInputs"
      :key="index"
    >
     <input
         v-model="formatTime" //want to use allFormatValues[index], instead
         id="time-input"      //but this loses the formatting if I change to 
                              //above
         type="text"
     />
  </div>
</div>
```

And

```
 watch: {
   formatTime () {
      const totalLength = this.formatTime.length;
      let a = this.formatTime.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
        .substr(0, 1);

      const b = this.formatTime.replace(/[^0-5]/g, "")
        .substr(1, 1);

      const c = this.formatTime.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
        .substr(2, 1);
      if (totalLength >= 2) {
        a = `${a.substring(0, 1)}:${b}${c}`;
      }
      this.formatTime = a;
    },
}
```

I have an array I want to loop through and set this value

```
data () {
  return {
  valueInputs: [],    // a list of inputs
  allFormatValues: [] // want to store all the formatted values here by the index
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `<input>`'s value to the iterator, and add an `input`-event handler that calls `formatTime()` to update `valueInputs`:

1. Bind `<input>.value` to the `input` variable:

   ```html
   <input :value="input" ...>
   ```
2. On the `<input>`, add an `input`-event handler that receives the iterator index and the event value:

   ```html
   <input @input="formatTime(index, $event.target.value)" ...>
   ```
3. Update the `formatTime()` method to receive the `index` and `$event.target.value` arguments. Also use [`vm.$set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) to reactively update `valueInputs[index]` with the new value:

   ```js
   export default {
     methods: {
       formatTime(index, input) {
         const totalLength = input.length;
         let a = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").substr(0, 1);

         //...

         this.$set(this.valueInputs, index, a)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rNyMzaO)

Comment: Awesome thank you, yes this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use computed properties.

First of all, make your input change original value.

```
<input v-model="input"
       id="time-input" 
       type="text"/>
```

Then, for cleaner code, make `formatValue` method

```
methods: {
    formatValue(value) {
        const totalLength = value.length
        let a = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
            .substr(0, 1)

        const b = value.replace(/[^0-5]/g, "")
            .substr(1, 1)

        const c = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
            .substr(2, 1)
        if (totalLength >= 2) {
            a = `${a.substring(0, 1)}:${b}${c}`
        }

        return a
    },
}
```

And finaly create computed property

```
computed: {
    formattedValues() {
        return this.valueInputs.map(value => this.formatValue(value))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting this error 'v-model' directives cannot update the iteration variable 'inputOfSet' itself. When I try to use v-model="input", do you know what alternative we can do here?

Comment: Also where does formattedValues get called? Index doesn't get passed in